# Is there a way to display a vertical arrow character in a linux terminal using ncurses?

Tags: linux, terminal, ncurses

I'm trying to reproduce an old GUI screen in my application that uses ncurses for terminal display. The old GUI used characters that looked like this: [image: Up and Down Arrows]

Is there a special ASCII code or other mechanism to do this with ncurses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the arrows in unicode, here you can find a list of [unicode arrows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29#Arrows_in_Unicode) and the relative codes.

`ncursesw` has the support to wide character set, you should just set the locale:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "")
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this plain old ncurses?  Apparently ncursesw isn't available with my distribution (Fedora)

Answer (score 2):

There are the alternate character set characters `ACS_UARROW` and `ACS_DARROW`, which you can display with `addch` and related functions, but what character they display depends on your terminal type.

Comment: Unfortunately, on my terminal the characters displayed were ^ for UARROW and ┴ for DARROW.

Answer (score 1):

If your terminal is unicode aware, your font can display unicode and your locale is set to unicode, you should be able to simply

```
echo '↑ or ↓'
```

Comment: What about within ncurses?